# openlayers-3 precompose, how to do layer clipping with a rectangular geometry

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm trying to make a simple app doing something similar to the [Layer Spy Example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/examples/layer-spy.html), but instead of a circle flowing the mouse pointer, I would like to do the clipping based on a rectangle which is always centered in the map. 
(preferably with "fixed" size" i.e. changes "extent" when zooming)

Any help appreciated
Thanks
Frode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like in the example that you are referring to. But instead of `context.arc()` use [`context.rect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rect) with a fixed position to clip the layer. Something like:

```
imagery.on('precompose', function(event) {
  var ctx = event.context;
  var pixelRatio = event.frameState.pixelRatio;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  var x = ctx.canvas.width / 2 - 100;
  var y = ctx.canvas.height / 2 - 100;
  ctx.rect(x, y, 100, 100);
  ctx.clip();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eo1c1x78/

Comment: Thanks tsauerwein! Just what I needed!